# How to only show 9 elements in each page thymeleaf

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, pagination, thymeleaf

I'm trying to only display 9 elements in my page from my list.

The next page I want to be able to display the next elements of the list.
I've been trying to figure out but I have no clue how to do it.

Here is my code

Html

```
div class="row-first">
  <div class="row-section" th:with="var=${9}" th:with="page=${1}">  
    <div class="column"  th:each="shoes,iterStat : ${shoesList}"   th:if="${iterStat.index} < ${var}">
```

This code manages to show only 9 elements in my page, but i want to use the variable "var" to change the index of my list depending on the number of my page

Javascript

```
 $(function () {
  var pageElements = /*[[${var}]]*/ 9;
  window.pagObj = $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
      totalPages: 35,
      visiblePages: 3,
      first: false,
      last: false,
      prev:"&#10094;",
      next: "&#10095;",
      prevClass: "previous",
      nextClass:"nextpage",
 
      
      onPageClick: function (event, page) {
          console.info(page + ' (from options)');
         
      }
  }).on('page', function (event, page) {
      console.info(page + ' (from event listening)');
      pageElements = pageElements * page;
      console.info(pageElements);
  });
```

Im using this library for pagination:
https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/#options-and-events